# Amount of bytes used by HttpRuntime.Cache?

Tags: asp.net, caching

Does anyone know how to find out (programatically) how much bytes are currently used by HttpRuntime.Cache?

Comment: This is not the solution you are looking for.

Comment: There's no easy way as far as I know. I suppose you could enumerate the items in the cache and use some reflection magic to get the total size of the object graph but that's not an easy thing to do at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not programatically, but you can use CLR Profiler from Microsoft. Start profiler, from File menu choose Set Parameters and enter location of web and port (/port:55000 /path:"c:..."). Then you can start web server with "Start App" and by choosing WebDev.WebServer.exe.
When web is started (it can feel slow when browsing pages!), and few pages opened (to fill cache or session), you can click on “Show Heap Now” and then click on "filter" and enter something like "system.web.caching" or "system.web.sessionstate".

Comment: I've found tutorials that use the CLR Profiler.
From my Vista machine I'm getting an windows api error 1060, complaining about a service that does not exist with the specified name...
Even CLR profiling a server and specifing the w3svc name manually doesn't work (it succeeds in starting and restarting, but it waits for the CLR runtime indefinately)

Comment: don't forget to set the working directory to the WebDev.Webserver.exe's path, otherwise the profiling will not run at all, will show "Waiting for application to start common language runtime" only.